# How to open files in a particular folder with randomly generated names?

Tags: python

How to open files in a particular folder with randomly generated names? I have a folder named `2018` and the files within that folder are named randomly. I want to iterate through all of the files and open them up.

I will post three names of the files as an example but note that there are over a thousand files in this folder so it has to work on a large scale without any hard coding.

`0a2ec2da-628d-417d-9520-b0889886e2ac_1.xml`

`00a6b260-951d-46b5-ab27-b2e8729e664d_1.xml`

`00a6b260-951d-46b5-ab27-b2e8729e664d_2.xml`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: Yep, good duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

In general, if you want to do something with files, it's worth glancing at the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html), [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and other built-in modules. They're all documented.

You could also use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) expansion to expand `"folder/*"` into a list of all the filenames, but `os.walk` is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

With `os.listdir()` or `os.walk()`, depending on whether you want to do it recursively or not.

You can go through the python doc

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

One you have list of files you can read it simply -

```
for file in files:
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        # perform file operations
```

Comment: How would you use the os.walk() if you want to open the files in a ascending order?